# Using useDelimiter() with a text file

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to use useDelimiters() to split up a text file by a certain delimiter instead of by each new line. For example in the following code I have this text file input which I want to split into two at the full stop:

```
hellothere
stop.hereok
asdf
```

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File text = new File("test.txt");
    Scanner filein = new Scanner(text).useDelimiter("\\.");
    System.out.println(filein.next());
    System.out.println(filein.next());
}
```

My output:

```
hellothere
stop
hereok
asdf
```

Expected output:

```
hellotherestop
hereokasdf
```

Anyone know the issue?

Comment: did you try `\n` as your delimiter

Comment: The scanner works like expected. You can remove newlines from the tokens like this: `System.out.println(filein.next().replaceAll("\\r|\\n", ""));`.

Comment: Thank you, I will also take this into consideration when continuing my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file contains text

```
hellothere
stop.hereok
asdf
```

it means that it contains characters which represents line separators (`\n` `\r` or `\r\n` depending on OS). Printing text until dot delimiter will also print these line separators, which means that first

```
System.out.println(filein.next());
```

will print

```
hellothere //<-here exists line separator character(s)
stop       //and here was dot, or end of your text
```

If you want it to print `hellotherestop` without line separators you need to remove them manually.

Since Java 8 you can use `\R` character class added to regex engine which represents separators like `\r\n` `\r` and few others.

```
System.out.println(filein.next().replaceAll("\\R",""));
```

If you are using older version of Java you can try with `replaceAll("\r?\n|\r","")`

Comment: Ah, I did not know OS dependent line separators were also an issue in Java, thank you for your response. Adding .replaceAll("\\R","") worked line a charm, thank you.